# Native TSQL support for parallel queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, parallel-processing

Is there native support for executing queries in parallel from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2? Take this pseudo code for example

```
create proc dbo.MySproc
as
   delete from SomeTable where Predicate = true [as parallel]
   delete from AnotherTable where Predicate = false [as parallel]

   [wait for queries]

   select * from SomeTable join AnotherTable on Predicate = true
```

I've seen examples of doing this but they require installing non native CLR procedures which is what I want to avoid.

**NOTE**: I'm not talking about execution plans, I mean running two non related queries at the same time async, not one after the other.

Comment: You could fire them from batch file.  I do this in some processes now.  Proc1 Proc2 Proc3 all execute in parallel and update a flagging table, Proc4 fires when all 3 flags are set

Comment: You mean batch file as in running them through osql?

Comment: Yes.  If you use `start` the batch file will kick off the command without waiting for completion, and will launch as many `osql` sessions as you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no T-SQL syntax for controlling parallelism.

There are a number of games you can play to get something similar but they all require a non T-SQL entity.  For example, SQL Server Jobs, CLR SPs that spawn multiple threads, C# app that spawns the threads, use of sqlcmd to execute T-SQL etc.

Answer (score 2):

[How can I run sql server stored procedures in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277900/how-can-i-run-sql-server-stored-procedures-in-parallel) - it's about stored procedures, but maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: +1 I'll talk to the DBA when he gets in and see if this is something we can do.