# How to call multiple stored procedures in parallel in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have 3 stored procedures in a SQL Server database.

```
EXEC sp_test_1 (ID)
GO

EXEC sp_test_2 (ID)
GO

EXEC sp_test_3 (ID)
GO
```

When I execute this, each stored procedure is taking 15 minutes to complete and total of 45 minutes.

When I execute each stored procedure in each session.

```
Session 1 : EXEC sp_test_1 (ID)

Session 2 : EXEC sp_test_2 (ID)

Session 3 : EXEC sp_test_3 (ID)
```

It is completed in 15 minutes and giving good performance gain.

I'm looking for any option in SQL Server to achieve parallelism and any other direction apart from SSIS .

Can any one suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run sql server stored procedures in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277900/how-can-i-run-sql-server-stored-procedures-in-parallel)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I have  gone through it  already but  enough concrete  answer to work out

Comment: Are you trying to call these 3 in parallel from any ETL tool or by using SQL only?

Comment: In ETL (SSIS) I know  the  Process . I'm looking  in SQL only

Comment: SQL is run sequentially, @mohan111 . You can't write a batch with multiple statements that are run at the same time. If you want to run 3 separate statements at the same time, you need 3 separate connections to run said statements. This is why you can achieve this in SSIS, as you have 3 Execute T-SQL Tasks, each running a different statement.

Comment: @mohan111 . . . You can use SQL Server Agent to create a job that runs separate steps in parallel.

Comment: Or use PowerShell to kick off 3 separate batches

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

first you should create a job every proc.

```
Declare @Job1 uniqueidentifier,
@Job2 uniqueidentifier,
@Job3 uniqueidentifier

-- CREATE JOB1
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = 'JOB1' , @job_id = @Job1 OUTPUT;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @Job1 , @server_name = N'(LOCAL)'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @Job1 , @step_name = 'execute' , @command = 'EXEC sp_test_1' , @database_name = 'DBNAME'

-- CREATE JOB2
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = 'JOB2' , @job_id = @Job2 OUTPUT;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @Job2 , @server_name = N'(LOCAL)'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @Job2 , @step_name = 'execute' , @command = 'EXEC sp_test_2' , @database_name = 'DBNAME'

-- CREATE JOB3
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = 'JOB3' , @job_id = @Job3 OUTPUT;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @Job3 , @server_name = N'(LOCAL)'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @Job3 , @step_name = 'execute' , @command = 'EXEC sp_test_3' , @database_name = 'DBNAME'
```

now you can execute proc be async like this

```
-- now you can, execute proc be async like this
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'JOB1';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'JOB2';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'JOB3';
```